# need to delete new line last of txt using php

Tags: php, curl, preg-replace, preg-match, str-replace

1. İstanbul  04:22
2. Bursa00  03:11
3. Ankara0 02:53
4. İzmir000 02:34
5. Kayseri0 02:47
6. 

I saved this lines to the txt by using curl but I couldnt delete the line 6. It is not blank. because i can delete blank lines. When i count the lines it shown 5 and when I make new functions it marks 6. I tried all preg match, str replace, preg replace but i failed. When I open the txt mouse cursor always on sixth'. What should i do (for "\n" i guess) ?

Comment: How about you do `var_dump()` on the variable first? This is not about text editors after all :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [rtrim](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) function to remove trailing carriage returns and linefeeds if they are present:

```
$str = rtrim($str, "\r\n");
```

An equivalent preg_replace call:

```
$str = preg_replace('/[\r\n]+$/', '', $str);
```